# Add Categories Tag to the end of Product Description in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm editing a WordPress eCommerce site and I need help adding something to a PHP file. I want to move the code that generates the tags to a different PHP file but I have not been able to do it successfully yet. I figured out that the line of code I need to move is this:

```
<?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Model:', 'Models:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

And this is the file I want to move it to:

```
<?php
/**
 * Description tab
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $post;

$heading = esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_description_heading', __( 'Product Description', 'woocommerce' ) ) );

?>

<?php if ( $heading ): ?>
  <h2><?php echo $heading; ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Just in case this matters, the page the line of code comes from is this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Meta
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $post, $product;

$cat_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
$tag_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );

?>
<div class="product_meta">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start' ); ?>

    <?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) : ?>

        <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php _e( 'PR PN:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku" itemprop="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></span><br>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Model:', 'Models:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

    <?php echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'OEM PN:', 'OEM PN:', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe those are template files.. Just edit those files...

Steps:

1. create a folder in your theme named woocommerce.
2. copy those templates files in in your theme woocommerce folder. Same hierarchy as if templates folder is your woocommerce folder. So your `plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\tabs\description.php` should be copied to `your-theme\woocommerce\single-product\tabs\description.php`
3. Do your edits on those files. and you're safe.

Source: [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: I believe she also wants to remove the code from the `meta.php` template, so she'll need to override that one. Depending on where she wants to move the categories too, it may be possible via hook/action.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you so much for your responses. I already know that I have to edit the template files. The problem I have is that I don't know how to make the edits. I tried copying the line of code that I want to move but it didn't show up. I think I'm missing something or I'm not doing it correctly.

Comment: @rixy, you might be missing the global $product?

Comment: @reigel that's what I was missing! Thank you so much!